# Different IsExpanded bindings for different types of TreeViewItem's

Tags: wpf, treeview

I want to use the following binding for `IsExpanded` of a `TreeViewItem`:

```
        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded}" />
            </Style>
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

but i need different bound properties for different `HierarchicalDataTemplate`'s.
In my case for the top level I need `{Binding PropertyX.IsExpanded}` and for the other levels just `{Binding IsExpanded}`.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer. For the **top level** use `TreeView.ItemContainerStyle`:

```
<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
         <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding PropertyX.IsExpanded}" />
     </Style>
</TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

For the **sub levels** use `HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle`:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
         <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded}" />
     </Style>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
```

To understand this, the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate.itemcontainerstyle(v=vs.110).aspx) says:
Gets or sets the Style that is applied to the item container for each **child item**. This means when you set the `HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle` for the object type displayed as the top level of the treeview, it is applied to its children. When you set it at the Treeview level it is applied to the top level object types.

The object type of the lowest level cannot expand, so it doens't need the `HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle`.

However the object type of the second last level inherits the Style from the level above it. Because it then is applied to it's *children*, i.e. the lowest level, it expects the `IsExpanded` property to be present on the lowest level ... which results in databinding errors. Setting `<Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="False"/>` on the second last level resolves this (the second last level can expand but its children cannot). Also a blank style `<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" />` resolves this.